# Azure Devops ecr login

Tags: docker, azure-devops, amazon-ecr

I am trying to login to ecr using a pipeline step in azure devops . After login i have a Docker file where the base image declared inside that file would be pulled from ecr and other steps combined and build a new image. So i have created a pipeline step of azure cli for login and trying to pull the base image bt its failing with no authentication provided like that. I have configured the correct service connection and passed into this azure devops step.

[image]

Comment: 1. Can you run the same command successfully in your **local** AWS CLI using the credential you provided in the AWS service connection? 2. You can try to supply credentials through named variables in your build or use AWS environment variables and check what's the result. See more info from [Supply task credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/getting-started.html#supplying-task-creds-overview).

Comment: Have you considered using a service connection for the ECR? This might help: https://medium.com/kocsistem/the-mystery-is-solved-between-azure-devops-and-aws-ecr-public-50a7204c0254